# Is there a way to search through the early journal issues of "Nature" and "Science" and read the issues online?

Tags: publishing, resource-recommendation

I'm working on an analysis of the use of the term "dogma/dogmatism" in 19th-century scientific periodicals, two of which are *Nature* (1869-) and *Science* (1880-). Basically, I search every issue for the term to then understand how often and in which context it was used.

I already found several online archives which provide (partially) access to the early issues: HathiTrust, Archive.org and several smaller or more specialised websites - apart from the journals' official archives. 
However, analysing every issue through those websites is nearly impossible. The official archives are only paid-to-use, while my usual databases (f.ex. HathiTrust) only have a very limited number of issues and archive.org or digicoll.library.wisc.edu have very poor search engines which a) are not very reliable and b) take a very long time to browse through one issue.

I wanted to ask **if somebody has experience with those journals and can tell me if there is a better way to finish this task?**

I am aware that I would probably be able to search them by wading through all those fragments of sources (or pay a lot of money to enter the official archives), which I will do if there is no other possibility. But I hope somebody can help me finding a smarter option.

Comment: Hire a bot. Surely there's one to do the job. Also, consider writing to those journals. Perhaps you can get a pleasant surprise that for such a research they may be able to release old materials.

Comment: Are you affiliated with a university? Have you asked a research librarian there to help you?

Comment: @nilon Could you specify on how to hire a bot, please?

Comment: @JonCuster Yes, I am affiliated to a university and I asked the research librarian who would be responsible for History of Sciences. They told me they could only provide the university's access (which did not help in my case). However, it might be worth it to ask somebody from a different department there.

Comment: @Alexander not sure. Try [scrappy](https://scrapy.org/), [selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/), or [a scrapper that uses python to connect to a database](https://towardsdatascience.com/web-scraping-news-articles-in-python-9dd605799558). Also please deliver feedback once you can solve the question.